# When using the Gurobi optimizer, if a time limit is specified, can I still retreive the best solution that Gurobi has got so far?

Tags: gurobi

The Gurobi optimizer provides a [time limit](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/timelimit.html) parameter. Given an optimization problem, Gurobi would stop when the specified time limit is reached. Is it possible to retrieve the current best solution that Gurobi has found so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Gurobi reaches the time limit it will return the status code *TIME_LIMIT*. However, if a solution was found so far (you can check this via the [SolCount attribute](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/solcount.html#attr:SolCount)), you can retrieve the values of the current best feasible solution via the [X attribute](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/x.html#attr:X).